# Can not validate nested array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When validating nested arrays with the same keys and rules, an incorrect error message will be picked up, for example, if the rules are:

```
$rules = [ 'elem.*.test' => 'required', 'elem.*.subitem.test' =>
'required', ];
```

and the messages:

```
$messages = [ 'elem.*.test.required' => 'top level item required', 'elem.*.subitem.test.required' => 'sub item required', ];
```

Comment: Can you show your regex?

Comment: @MaratBadykov it's $pattern = str_replace('\*', '.*', $pattern);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Str::is()` is called in FormatsMessages::getFromLocalArray().

You can't use

```
str_replace('*', '[^.]*', $sourceKey)
```

because it gets escaped by preg_quote().

You could add a

```
$wildcard = '.*'
```

parameter to `Str::is()` and override it with `'[^.]*'`

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22499

You can fix it by swapping the messages:

```
$messages = [
    'elem.*.subitem.test.required' => 'sub item required',
    'elem.*.test.required' => 'top level item required'
];
```